# Making my Java program easily distributable

Tags: java, deployment, dll, installation, java-3d

I have installed the Java 3D API on PC via the exe installer, which simply created a new directory with `j3dcore.jar`, `vecmath.jar`, `j3dutils.jar` in a lib sub-directory and `j3dcore-ogl.dll` in a bin sub-directory.

Netbeans had no issues and my code compiled and executed smoothly, however once I built my project and tried to run it from the command prompt I got an `UnsatisfiedLinkError` saying that `no j3dcore-ogl in java.library.path`.

Google came to the rescue and gave me 3 viable solutions:

- by copying the dll file into my JRE's bin directory
- by adding the path of the dll file to the library path (`java -Djava.library.path=dllpath`)
- load the dll in the program with `System.load()` (I couldn't get this one to work, actually)

My question is: Is there an elegant solution to this problem, that I missed?

It seems tedious that for each different PC someone would like to use this program on, he'd have to either copy the dll or add it to the library path before it can run. (Side question: How come Netbeans didn't have a problem with the dll?)

Comment: Judging by the name ("APi"), this is not a standalone program, but a library for you to use in your own java applications.

Comment: this is what installers are for ...

Comment: Maybe I wasn't quite clear enough: even my own PC, where I have installed Java3D had this issue outside Netbeans

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Edit - After re-reading your question, your issue sounds different.  However I'm able to get my running like so, by just dropping all dll files in the same directory as the .bat file starting the java process:*

*java -classpath ./YourJar.jar;./lib/j3dcore.jar;./lib/vecmath.jar;./lib/j3dutils.jar package.MainClass*

*And that works on multiple user's PCs, so I know simply dropping it in the working directory works.*

I believe it depends on the version of Java being used - 64 bit or 32 bit.  The correct dll file (of the same name) needs to be in the working directory.

I think I was getting a similar problem when the wrong dll was being used, and it's not OS-dependent (if your 64 bit OS has 32-bit Java installed, you'd need the 32 bit j3dcore-ogl.dll file).

So the question is, which version of Java are you using *(when running outside of your IDE)*, and which version of the dll are you putting (if any) in the working directory? I don't need any dll files in my path settings to get this working on other's PCs, and did not use System.load(), and did NOT copy files into my user's JRE/bin directory - so I know this is possible without the 3 options you mention.

Comment: By the way, also to solve the 32-64 bit problem I believe you'll have to copy the appropriate version of the dll into the working directory, with the expected name. A bit messy, but automatic enough for the user that it's still a double-click of the .bat to start.

Comment: Also, if you've already tried dropping the dll file into the working directory that you're running from -look closely. I did that, forgetting to add 3 *other* dll dependencies, and got a very similar looking error mentioning a different dll which I took for the original error message for the first dll. Took me a bit of head scratching to figure that one out. After I dropped the others in the working directory, all works fine, and on my user's PCs too.

Answer (score 1):

> Making my Java program easily distributable

If you mean 'easy for the end user' look to [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).

---

A passer-by asks:

> Can you package the dll dependencies with Web Start?

Yes, but much, much better.  You can package the natives for each platform in separate Jars, and supply them only to the platform that uses that native, even so far as partitioning the download between 32 & 64 bit versions of the natives.

JWS puts the natives on the run-time class-path of the application, ready for loading in code.

This all happens automatically for the end user, they click a link, approve the trust dialog(s) when asked, and the application installs - possibly with desktop integration, and appears on screen like magic.

JWS apps. that use natives need to be distributed as `all-permissions` security level, because the JVM cannot guarantee the actions of anything that 'goes native'.

Comment: Can you package the dll dependencies with Web Start? I *assume* you can (?), but without those most users aren't going to be happy.

Comment: Good show. Likely harder to get working right, but 'nicer" than a .bat

Comment: @Crusader: "Likely harder to get working right,.."  Too bloody right!  All that ease for the end user comes at a cost to the developer.  ;)  But then, while it 'costs' more time & effort initially, it saves a lot in 'support costs' in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

If you put the dlls in the same directory than you Jar, does it work?
If yes, you could consider distributing it like this.

Comment: I had that idea. Tryed putting the dll in with the 3 j3d jars that need to be distributed anyway, and loading it in my code with System.load(), sadly it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I guess DLL are searched in all folders in %PATH% on windows. (LD_LIBRARY_PATH for  UNIX flavors)

Could you try by adding the path to dll  to %path% variable?

It appears that you are trying package a product with many jars as dependencies. You may benefit from  [One-Jar](http://one-jar.sourceforge.net/index.php?page=details&file=native). It claims to have native dll support.